# Validation check on inputs

Tags: anchor, pda, validation

I have a `sign_up` function :

```
pub fn sign_up(ctx: Context<SignUp> , user_name: String , phone: String , email: String) -> Result<()> {// Code is here }
```

and one of the arguments is `user_name` and i need to check the `user_name` that has been sent to be unique among all accounts that is being created with this function and that requires me to look at other users `user_name` as check whether the `user_name` is taken or not ? and other usernames are in the data accounts of other users .

Note : I have also other arguments i need to check out the validation.

What do you guys suggest me to do ?

I don't know if PDA will work for this .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added some code what do expect ?

Comment: You should add the SignUp context accounts

Comment: U can create a PDA with the user_name. Since a PDA can be initialized only once, so if the user_name is not unique, then it will throw an error saying that the PDA is already initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PDA for you user account like so:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name: String)]
pub struct SignUp<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = UserState::LEN,
        seeds = [b"user".as_ref(), name.as_bytes()]
        bump,
        constraint = some_validation_function(name),
    )]
    pub user: Account<'info, UserState>,
    
    /// The rest of your context accounts
}
```

Using the name provided as a function argument (don't forget to update the program function accordingly) in the account seeds makes sure the acccount has a unique name. If you need more validation, you can use a constraint as shown above.

Later, you can work without passing the argument by using directly the name if you stored it in the user account:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct OtherFunction<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"user".as_ref(), user.name.as_bytes()]
        bump,
    )]
    pub user: Account<'info, UserState>,
    
    /// The rest of your context accounts
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the answer and do you have any project source code related to this ?

Comment: Is name a property of UserState struct ? and if not how can i access properties of the user in seeds ?

Comment: In my example, `name` is a function parameter. You can also have a name variable in your account struct and access it to create a seeds buffer

Comment: I would appreciate if you can give me a code example .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, PDAs are exactly what you should use. That enforces uniqueness and makes it such that only one possible address can be generated for a particular username. Other attempts to sign-up with the same username would then fail.